# Refactoring a function JS

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with my code. First, i did this code and it works well. I have two modals and i wanna to rewrite.

```
// Modal Carrinho
const openModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="open"]');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="close"]');
const container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container"]');
openModal.addEventListener('click', changeModal);
closeModal.addEventListener('click', changeModal);
container.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

function changeModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.toggle('active');
}

function closeModal(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    changeModal(e);
  }
}

//Modal Compra
const openModal2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="openCompra"]');
const closeModal2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="closeCompra"]');
const container2 = document.querySelector('[data-modal="containerCompra"]');
openModal2.addEventListener('click', changeModal2);
closeModal2.addEventListener('click', changeModal2);
container2.addEventListener('click', closeModal2);

function changeModal2(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container2.classList.toggle('active');
}

function closeModal2(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    changeModal(e);
  }
}
```

I tried it, but it doesn't works

```
function createModal(nome) {
   var openModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="open' + nome + '"]');
   var closeModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="close' + nome + '"]');
   var container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container' + nome + '"]');

   openModal.addEventListener('click', changeModal);
   closeModal.addEventListener('click', changeModal);
   container.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
}

function changeModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.toggle('active');
}

function closeModal(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    changeModal(e);
  }
}


// E para usar:
createModal("");
createModal("Compra");
```

So this error appear and i don't know how to solve and simplify this script "modal.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.mudarModal".

Comment: If the code works and you are looking to rewrite/refactor it, this question belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `changeModal` relies on a scoped variable `container` which your refactoring eliminated from the function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error explains the problem, the container is undefined since you define in function `createModal` as below -

`var container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container' + nome + '"]');`

To solve this, you should try to get the `container` from the DOM by using `querySelector` and transversing to current context `container`.

Or alternatively, you can pass the parameter `nome` to the change modal function and get the `container` from DOM again -

```
    function createModal(nome) {
      var callChangeModal = (event) => changeModal(event, nome);
      var callCloseModal = (event) => closeModal(event, nome);
      var openModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="open' + nome + '"]');
      var closeModal = document.querySelector('[data-modal="close' + nome + '"]');
      var container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container' + nome + '"]');

      openModal.addEventListener('click', callChangeModal);
      closeModal.addEventListener('click', callChangeModal);
      container.addEventListener('click', callCloseModal);
    }

    function changeModal(e, nome) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var container = document.querySelector('[data-modal="container' + nome + '"]');
      container.classList.toggle('active');
    }

    function closeModal(e, nome) {
      if (e.target === this) {
        changeModal(e, nome);
        }
      }


      // E para usar:
      createModal("");
      createModal("Compra");
```

Comment: `changeModal(e, nome;` is missing a closing `)`. Also, how do you want to make the event trigger pass that additional argument?

Comment: @connexo, Sorry, that's a typo. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing out. I am binding a local arrow function to the event, and the arrow function itself has additional parameter in its definition. The parameter is passed since the arrow function will be created twice with different parameters and will be bind to the click event. It is as good as writing 2 click event handlers, but here the code is just refactored so its concise and reusable.